# Storing files in PersistentDataPath without going through StreamingAssets on Android and iOS

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've created a build pipeline script, which allows me to build my app for `Android` and `iOS`.

I don't know how to manage assets, which remotely update.

**What I do atm**

I have about 100 files, each one is 20MB in size.

I am able to copy these files to `StreamingAssets` at build time.

Because `StreamingAssets` is `read only`, when I want to use an asset, I copy it to `persistentDataPath`, check if there is a new version of the file on my remote server and if yes - download it. I then read the fresh content from the `persistentDataPath`...

**My problem**

When I ship the app it already has the files in `StreaminAssets`, I then duplicate them in `persistentData`, which makes my app take twice as much space on the device.

Is there a way to build the game with the files added to `persistentDataPath` directly without going through the `StreamingAssets` path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simply entirely skip the part about `StreamingAssets`?

=> Check if

- file exists is missing in persitentDataPath
- or there is a newer version on your server

=> In both cases download (and replace)

Sure it takes a bit longer the first time you open the app, but this is actually how most apps work nowadays.

---

If you are asking about directly and immediately unpacking files into `persistentDataPath` when installing the app:

I don't think there is a more direct way for this.

If you want the app to contain all content already from the beginning, well then yes, it needs to be all packed into the APK which you can't remove content from later on.

---

Alternatively you could also give [Addressables](https://unity.com/how-to/simplify-your-content-management-addressables) a look which supports caching as well.

Comment: I would like to provide an experience in which the user can enjoy the game right away instead of getting into the game and having to download a bunch of files. This is especially problematic if they are not on wi-fi. I will most definitely end up having a users stuck in a game with no content.

Comment: @Ando well there is absolutely no way whatsoever to have your app with all content ready to use ... without packing all that content into the apk which as to my understanding is what you currently are trying to avoid ...

Comment: I didn't mean that. I meant that I want to pack the content directly in a writable directory `persistentData`. I wanted to ship the app with content, move everything to `persistentData`, which I know is writable and get rid of the initial content. I can't remove anything from `StreamingAssets`. I thought there is some other way to accomplish fairly straight forward process. Your comments/answers kinda tells me that something like that is not possible.

Comment: I would go for the "load stuff on first app start" way .. the moment the user installs your app they have internet (otherwise how would they download your app in the firs place) so you can assume that they can also load the content once at the beginning. Again, most bigger apps work this way so it is known to users that the first start might require more time and data connection